# What is the correct way to schedule tasks in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

As explained in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#introduction), you can set a cronjob to execute laravel scheduler

I want to run tasks, every wednesday, every two hours starting at 13:00.

I placed the scheduler in Command Kernel for everyhour I want the task to run. But this doesn't work.

```
// project/app/Console/Kernel.php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->wednesdays()
             ->at('13:00')
             ->at('15:00')
             ->at('17:00')
             ->at('19:00')
             ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

What would be the correct way to set up the schedule for every two hours starting at 13:00  every wednesdays?

I would prefer not using a cronjob expression (`* 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 * * 3` ) because It's confusing.

Comment: you can use expression `13-20` as well

Comment: @ZahurSh could you provide an example?

Comment: expression in my crontab `*/5     4-17    *       *       *       `
means every 5 minutes from 4 to 17 hours

Comment: Just use the cron job. It's not that bad. If you're worried that you'll forget it or that someone else who looks at it later may not understand it, make a comment about it in the code explaining it and how to access it.